# Fill parent div based on child height/width

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a expanding menu that appends the parent div with multiple 400px smaller divs until the full parent div is filled.

In the for loop i'm checking if .background is the same height as .main-nav, if it isn't then continue to add the .slice divs.

The issue I'm having is that once .background is the same height as .main-nav it stops adding the .slices divs which means the full width isn't covered.

*P.S First 'real'JS project; sorry if my code is messy.*

The following JSFiddle will make more sense:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ryAD/13/

**JS:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var s = document.getElementsByClassName('slice');
    var m = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName('background')[0];
    var a = document.getElementById('main-nav');

    var w = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    m.addEventListener('click', function() {

        m.classList.add('open');

            for(var i = b.clientHeight; i < a.clientHeight; i++) {

         var c = document.getElementsByClassName('slice')[0];
         var d = c.cloneNode(true);

         if(b.clientHeight == a.clientHeight) {
             break;
           } else {
             c.parentNode.appendChild(d);
           }
         }

         for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
                   s[i].style.opacity = 1;
                 } 

    }, false);

}());
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="master">

    <a id="btn-nav">
        <span></span>
        <span>Menu</span>
        <span></span>
    </a>

    <nav id="main-nav">

            <div class="background" >

                <div class="slice"></div>

            </div>

    </nav>

</div><!-- end master -->
```

Comment: first thing's first, I recommend using jQuery.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to learn JavaScript which JQuery was written in?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Check my JSfiddle. On the last row the parent div doesn't get filled completely, it stops at the first slice because both parent and child are the same height. I want to be able to completely cover the parent div height and width ways.

Comment: You mean when you click on it, you want the whole background to change from blue to black color?

Comment: No, onClick - I need multiple <div class="slice"></div> to be added inside .background until the whole <div class="background"></div> is completely filled with multiple .slices. Makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: Here's another Fiddle with only one slice showing on click. Line 23 is where the slices get added. http://jsfiddle.net/8ryAD/18/

Comment: `if(b.clientHeight == a.clientHeight)` This will be true when the first slice is written to second row. You need to calc the width into this logic

Comment: Ok @Papa I will have a go. Thanks

Comment: Also, be careful using `document.getElementsByClassName` all the time. It will trawl all elements on a page and isn't very efficient. Better to run this within a container eg `a.getElementsByClassName('slice')`.

Comment: I try to understand what you really want.  Is it something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8ryAD/38/)?

Comment: Do you want to cover all of the screen with the "slices" or is there a set number you want to display? And if there is a set number of them do you want them to fit into a visible area?

Comment: The whole screen based on the screen size. No set number of slices, just enough to cover the viewport :-) Thanks

Comment: @ForguesR Yes something like that just need the slices to cover the whole viewport onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is the for loop.  For that particular case you should use a while loop.  For loop are used when you know precisely the number of iterations you are going to do.

I reworked the loop this way :

```
// Loop while we don't cover client surface
while(dsWidth <  a.clientWidth*(a.clientHeight / c.clientHeight)) {
  var d = c.cloneNode(true);
  c.parentNode.appendChild(d);
  dsWidth = dsWidth + d.clientWidth;  
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ryAD/80/) doing the job. It is not clear if you want to add "slices" vertically or horizontally.  I chose horizontally but you should have no difficulties .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It needs to fill horizontally until the whole viewport is filled. In your example the blue area needs to be covered. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ryAD/64/ - though mine only works because I over add .slice elements. I need it to only add the right amount of slices.

Comment: See my updated answer.  I modified the slice height to 20px to demonstrate how it fills perfectly the parent surface.